# Auto-truncate neo4j messages.log file

Tags: neo4j

The messages.log files from a bunch of neo4j indexes are taking up significant disk space on my servers. How can neo4j be configured to auto-truncate this file, or perhaps reduce the amount of information logged?

Example messages.log file:

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.5G Jul 15 16:33 /var/www/carboncloud/couchdb-neo4j-deft/couchdb-neo4j-deft-0.9.1/indexes/89d4d8e6-e072-44a6-9852-6598013560e3/messages.log

Sample of messages.log content:

```
2014-03-19 15:28:07,477 INFO  [neo4j.txmanager]: TM new log: tm_tx_log.1
2014-03-19 15:28:07,483 INFO  [neo4j.xafactory]: Opened logical log [/var/www/carboncloud/couchdb-neo4j-deft/couchdb-neo4j-deft-0.9.1/indexes/89d4d8e6-e072-44a6-9852-6598013560e3/index/lucene.log.1] version=0, lastTxId=1 (clean)
2014-03-19 15:28:07,488 DEBUG [neo4j.diagnostics]: --- STARTUP diagnostics START ---
2014-03-19 15:28:07,488 DEBUG [neo4j.diagnostics]: Neo4j Kernel properties:
2014-03-19 15:28:07,489 DEBUG [neo4j.diagnostics]: forced_kernel_id=
2014-03-19 15:28:07,489 DEBUG [neo4j.diagnostics]: read_only=false
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can:

In the neo4j.properties there is a setting called:

```
keep_logical_logs=true
```

Change it to something like:

```
keep_logical_logs=200M size
```

or

```
keep_logical_logs=7 days
```

Comment: Hey Ron, I think this setting refers to files with names like "nioneo_logical.log". My issue is with the "messages.log" file getting too big.

Comment: I think you are right. I've looked into the code and as far as I can see there, the default log rotation is at 100MB with max 2 rotating files, so I don't get why your log file is 1.5G.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no direct way to rotate `messages.log` from within Neo4j. However this can be easily achieved by external tools like [logrotate](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/logrotate-examples/). To completely flush it at runtime you might do a `cat /dev/null > messages.log`.